# div centered on screen but out of <html> and <body>

Tags: html, css

The following `html` creates a page with `<html>` height = 8, `<body>` height = 0, and yet the `div` with "Centered" is centered vertically as well on the screen. How is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style=" height:100px; width:200px;  margin: auto;  position: absolute;  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
        Centered
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because your `html` height is `8px` and your `div` height is `100px` and position is absolute, so whatever size your body/html is, `div` will be positioned `"absolutely"` where you set so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `position:absolute;`, the element takes it's position relative to the closest ancestor with a defined position property, which is the window in this case. This means that any heights you define in parent elements are completely redundant for the positioning of this element. It's positions exactly where you want it to, relative to the window.

If you don't want this behaviour try looking at [this website](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) to decide which position to use, and try adding position properties to parent elements.

Comment: Thanks. I thought `<body>` was its ancestor, but you're right. (Can't accept yet.)

Comment: When the parent is set to `position:relative;`, `position:absolute;` will refer to the bounds of that element, not the browser window. FYI

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add key parts to that explanation. Thanks for that @Mastrianni!

Answer (score 1):

Because it's `relative` to the `window`. If you add `position: relative;` to a parent element such as the `body` element then it will not be vertically centered on the screen unless the height spans the window height.

Answer (score 0):

`body` `height` is zero since the only `div` inside is absolute, and will not cause the `body` to grow in height.

There is default `8px` `margin` for body, which cause the html to grow `8px` `height`.

the absolute div is relative to body. and the left, right, top, bottom values  forces the div to center at equal distance from sides